# Which compression types are supported by zless?

Tags: command-line, compression, unzip, less

I just learned about the amazing [`zless`](https://man.netbsd.org/zless.1) command which allows me to write `zless file.txt.gz` instead of the more verbose `gunzip -c file.txt.gz | less` - in fact `less` is often configured to do this uncompression under the hood saving you even the `z`.

Unfortunately, `zstd` compression doesn't seem to be supported by `zless`.

I went on a search to find out which compression formats are supported by `zless` and to my surprise I couldn't find out even after an extend google search. The best I could find was:

> zmore is a filter that allows the viewing of files compressed with Lempel-Ziv encoding.  Such files generally have a `Z` or `gz` extension (both the compress(1) and gzip(1) formats are supported)

Now `xz` isn't explicitly mentioned in the above, but it still seems to be supported.

Does anyone know which formats are supported exactly? In contrast to most modern software where you can find the source code on Github/lab - I haven't really figured out yet how to find source code for these traditional unix tools.

For `zstd` one needs to use `zstdless` which does the job - albeit with 3 more characters.

Comment: I checked `zless` and it is bash script which you can open in text editor. And it uses `gzip`. You can find full path to this script using `which zless`

Comment: `zstdless` is also bash script - `zstdcat "$@" | less`. So maybe you could use it all to create own script which recognizes file extension and uses `zless` or `zstdless`